# jQuery/Javascript - Sort Table Columns Based on Totals Row

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

How can a sort be performed on table columns based on the sort of the last totals row?

For example, with the following table structure the row titled "Total Sold %" would be used to sort the corresponding columns in value from high to low. Thus, the columns would shift left or right so that the "Total Sold %" row is sorted **12.42%, 12.64%, 14.73%**:

```
<table class="table table-bordered text-center">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="text-center">
        Average
      </th>
      <th class="text-center">
        Entry #1
      </th>
      <th class="text-center">
        Entry #2
      </th>
      <th class="text-center">
        Entry #3
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">
        New Car Total Leads
      </th>
      <td>
        251
      </td>
      <td>
        227
      </td>
      <td>
        526
      </td>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">
        Appointments Shown %
      </th>
      <td>
        61%
      </td>
      <td>
        61%
      </td>
      <td>
        61%
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">
        Sold (Delivered)
      </th>
      <td>
        28
      </td>
      <td>
        37
      </td>
      <td>
        85
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">
        Total Sold %
      </th>
      <td>
        12.64%
      </td>
      <td>
        12.42%
      </td>
      <td>
        14.73%
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: That's a big question, it's like asking us to do the work for you... you haven't even tried anything yet, have you?

Comment: Not a question for work -- just a general question for knowledge and to provide a possible answer for others.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can proceed that way:

1. Find the row *R* containing the data to sort from and sort its data cells. Store those sorted cells in *S*
2. On each rows *r*, sort each data cells *c* as in *S*

   1. Find the index of *c* in *r*. This is *i*
   2. Find the cell *C* at *R*[*i*]
   3. Get the position of *C* in *S*. This is our target index in the array, sort with it
3. Append each cell in order to the row. It will replace all cells at the right position

**This code is broken, please see below**

```js
$('#sort').click(sort);

function sort() {
  var $table = $('table'),
    $sorted = $table.find('tbody tr').last().children().slice(1).sort(function(a, b) {
      return parseFloat(a.textContent) - parseFloat(b.textContent)
    });
  $table.find('tr').each(function() {
    var $row = $(this);
    $row.children().slice(1).sort(function(a, b) {
      return $sorted.eq($(a).index() - 1).index() - $sorted.eq($(b).index() - 1).index();
    }).each(function() {
      $row.append(this);
    });
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="sort">
  Sort
</button>
<table class="table table-bordered text-center">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="text-center">
        Average
      </th>
      <th class="text-center">
        Entry #1
      </th>
      <th class="text-center">
        Entry #2
      </th>
      <th class="text-center">
        Entry #3
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">
        New Car Total Leads
      </th>
      <td>
        251
      </td>
      <td>
        227
      </td>
      <td>
        526
      </td>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">
          Appointments Shown %
        </th>
        <td>
          61%
        </td>
        <td>
          61%
        </td>
        <td>
          61%
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">
          Sold (Delivered)
        </th>
        <td>
          28
        </td>
        <td>
          37
        </td>
        <td>
          85
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">
          Total Sold %
        </th>
        <td>
          12.64%
        </td>
        <td>
          12.42%
        </td>
        <td>
          14.73%
        </td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Of course, that is just one of all the possible solution, and not the faster one. Otherwise, you could try to parse your Table in an array (rows) of arrays (cells), sort, then reinsert the table. It would avoid to do so many jQuery calls, rather slow & memory consuming

---

**Edit**: Above code won't work in most situations, because I omitted that the JavaScript `sort` algorithm assumes that elements are moved just after the execution of the inner function, so indexes changes at each iteration. My previous code didn't do that, so it does not work.

Here is the fixed version

```js
$('#sort').click(sort);

function sort() {var LEFT_ROWS = 1,
    $table = $('table'),
    $sorted = $table.find('tbody tr').last().children().slice(LEFT_ROWS);
  $sorted = $sorted.sort(function(a, b) {
    return parseFloat(a.textContent) - parseFloat(b.textContent);
  });
  $table.find('tr').each(function() {
    var $row = $(this),
      $rowContent = $row.children().slice(LEFT_ROWS);
    $rowContent.toArray().map(function(t) {
      return $sorted.eq($(t).index() - LEFT_ROWS).index() - LEFT_ROWS
    }).sort(function(a, b) {
      var diff = a - b;
    }).forEach(function(i) {
      $row.append($rowContent.eq(i));
    });
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="sort">
  Sort
</button>
<table class="table table-bordered text-center">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="text-center">
        Average
      </th>
      <th class="text-center">
        Entry #1
      </th>
      <th class="text-center">
        Entry #2
      </th>
      <th class="text-center">
        Entry #3
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">
        New Car Total Leads
      </th>
      <td>
        251
      </td>
      <td>
        227
      </td>
      <td>
        526
      </td>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">
          Appointments Shown %
        </th>
        <td>
          61%
        </td>
        <td>
          61%
        </td>
        <td>
          61%
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">
          Sold (Delivered)
        </th>
        <td>
          28
        </td>
        <td>
          37
        </td>
        <td>
          85
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">
          Total Sold %
        </th>
        <td>
          12.64%
        </td>
        <td>
          12.42%
        </td>
        <td>
          14.73%
        </td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: That works great for 3 columns, when I add a 4th while playing around with it in JSFiddle, it breaks. Why is that?

Comment: The second piece works like magic for up to 10 rows. If I add an 11th, it breaks.

Comment: When using Google Chrome does this only seem to be an issue.

Comment: Hi,

Well, i’ve tried in some other extreme situations, and it works well… I can’t help you more, sorry. If you find the bug, please tell me, I’ll hit myself on the forehead shouting « But yes, obviously! Aaaarrrg! ». Have a nice coding day